# revealViewController is nil when I segue between one viewController to another in different storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I using RWRevealViewController in app. I have a slide menu with couple of cells and each cell is pointed to a viewController. Also, each viewController is embedded in navigationController.

My case is that I have a viewController "A" and viewController "B". If I want to go to any of them, I use the slide menu. However, there is a button in viewController "B" that if I tapped on it, it takes me to viewController "A". In this case, if I want to show viewController "A" with navigation bar and bar button item that shows the slide menu, I used this

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "A")
    self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This solution works fine if it is in they are in Main storyboard. However, if each one of viewControllers in separate storyboard, I have to specify that storyboard of viewController "A". So, I used this solution

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "A", bundle: nil)
    let A = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "navA")
    present(A, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

In here, The main story board have the container view "SWRevealViewController", slide menu viewController, and a storyboard reference to each viewControllers "A" and "B"

- Storyboard name of viewController "A" --> A.storyboard
- Storyboard id of navigatoinViewController of viewController "A" --> navA
- storyboard reference id of viewController "A" is --> navA

So, when I do that, every thing works except that bar button item does not show the slide menu because revealViewController is equal to nil

The action of bar button item

```
func sideMenus () {
    if revealViewController() != nil {
        menuBtn.target = revealViewController()
        menuBtn.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
        revealViewController().rearViewRevealWidth = screenSize.width * 0.75
        view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
    }
}
```

How can I fix this?

I am sorry it is to long but excuse me I could not find a shorter way to explain it

Thanks in advance

Comment: I haven't used that RWReveal in a long time but I think you want to just transition to the existing view controller A through the reveal segue, instead of creating a new one.

Comment: Could please tell me how to do that

Comment: I think you can ask the reveal controller to perform the front segue, IIRC.

Comment: I found the solution. I used their custom push method instead of swift present function which is revealViewController().pushFrontViewController(A, animated: true)